# Vuex - Passing specific state as a parameter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

In Vuex, I have two states that I want to mutate with the same function. Is there any way to pass the exact state you want to mutate, so that in `mutations` I wouldn't have to repeat the same function several times for it to work?

What I have now

```
state: {
    firstparam:'',
    secondparam:''
},
mutations: {
  addLimit: function (state, payload) {
    state.firstparam = payload;
  },
  addSecondLimit: function (state, payload) {
    state.secondparam = payload;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the param name you want to mutate as a property in the payload.

```
//to mutate firstparam
StorageEvent.commit('addLimit', {prop: 'firstparam', value: 'change'})

//to mutate secondparam
StorageEvent.commit('addLimit', {prop: 'secondparam', value: 'change'})
```

And use that `prop` property of payload to mutate that particular property

```
state: {
  firstparam:'',
  secondparam:''
},
mutations: {
  addLimit: function (state, payload) {
    state[payload.prop] = payload.value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! That was exactly what I was looking for!